# MVC design, trying to decouple my code

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

So I'm still learning and this is what I've done.  I have a model class that talks to a sqlite DB.  I have a ViewController that shows a popover (FilterViewController).  In the popover, there are some different options, like segment controls, a button to push a tableView, etc.  All of these options are for a filter to filter out what is shown to the user.

In this class, based on user selection, I update the model.  Then when the updates are done, I post a notification to the MainViewController class that handles all the other view (tabbars, search bars, navigation bars, etc).  Then in that class, it knows the data was changed and alters the view for the user with the filtered out data.

Is this an ok design?  I wonder how MVC works to keep the View, Controller, and Model separate.  But it seems like in my FilterViewCtlr, I get input from the user (view), and update the model.  Is this how it should work?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how it should work. The job of a controller is to mediate the view/model interactions.